# Php error trying to update MongoDB array

Tags: php, mongodb

I have some documents in mongodb that look like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576f46ca6803fab30e7b23c8"), 
  "username" : "Dallas", 
  "likes" : [ "576f46ca6803fab30e7b23c8", "576f4c446803faae0e7b23c9" ]}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("576f46ca6803fab31e7b23c8"), 
  "username" : "Dallas", 
  "likes" : [ ]}

<?php

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->testing;
$collection = $db->testCollection;

addLike();

//Add likes
function addLike()
{

$id = new MongoId("576f46ca6803fab30e7b23c8");

$collection->update(array('_id' => $id),array('$addToSet' => array('likes' => '4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157')));

echo 'addLike seemed to work';
}
```

I know the line of code that is wrong (syntax-wise I'm guessing) is the line that does the ...->`update()`

If i comment this out, I make it to the echo.

What I'm trying to do is store all of the `user ids` inside of the likes array, as you see one of the posts has an empty array, that's how I plan to start all posts.

I am confused as to why this code doesn't work, I pretty much copied it directly from here

**EDIT:**

To add, I really like what the above post says about it not allowing it to make duplicates when using `$addToSet`. As it shouldn't be possible for the user to like a post more than once, there is never a time the id should be in more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears all of my code was actually correct, except for some failure to understand php syntax.

I was under the impression that creating a collection variable outside of the function was global, It turned out that it didn't want me to call collection inside of that function so by deleting the function it was fixed.